# When creating a new ASP.NET app in Rider, can you do so using a local SQL Server instead of SQLite?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, rider

I'm getting started with Rider and have mostly written console apps so far. When selecting the template in new project creation I select ASP.NET Core Web Application. This creates a new SQLite DB and builds the project file using `options.UseSqlite();`. Is there a way to generate a new project using a local Sql Server and the `options.UseSqlServer();` code in the `Program.cs` file?

Comment: Feature requests like that can go to JetBrains, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can  Rider allows you to create and install additional project templates. [The docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Creating_and_Opening_Projects_and_Solutions.html#create-custom-project-template) are pretty good, so just give it a try.